# r Agrupando colunas e calculando médias em todas a colunas

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

Tenho essse conjunto de dados:

```
mes <- c("jan","fev","jan","abr","fev","abr","jan","fev","abr")
a <- c(32.3,32.7,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,33.4,34.9)
b <- c(19.2,19.2,19.6,19.7,19.7,19.9,20.0,20.0,20.4)
c <- c(14.7,15.0,15.6,16.2,16.4,17.0,17.7,18.3,19.1)
d <- c(24.2,24.3,24.7,25.0,25.5,26.4,26.7,27.1,27.6) 
temp <- data.frame(mes,a,b,c,d)
```

Estou agrupando da seguinte forma, usando o pacote `dplyr`

```
base <- temp %>% 
  group_by(mes) %>% 
  summarise(n = length(mes), med.a = mean(a), 
            med.b=mean(b),med.c=mean(c),med.d=mean(d))
```

Eu gostaria de agrupar pela coluna `mes` do `data.frame` contando o número de observações e também calculando as médias para todas as colunas de uma só vez, sem precisar dar nome a cada coluna nova que vai ser calculada a média.

tem como fazer esse procedimento? eu gostaria de escrever de uma forma que eu pudesse utilizar outros `data.frame` com diferentes números de colunas sem precisar dar nomes sempre a elas. Para o processo ficar automático e rodar em outras bases de dados que eu tenho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma coluna nova com as contagens utilizando `mutate`. A seguir, use `summarise_each` para dizer qual função deve ser aplicada a cada variável, exceto a primeira.

```
library(dplyr)
temp %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  summarise_each(mean, -1)
##         a        b        c        d n
##1 33.21111 19.74444 16.66667 25.72222 9
```

Esta solução supõe que sempre a primeira coluna será categórica. Caso a coluna categórica se chame `mes`, é possível resolver este problema chamando-a pelo seu nome:

```
temp %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  summarise_each(mean, -mes)
##         a        b        c        d n
##1 33.21111 19.74444 16.66667 25.72222 9
```